# Restart Timer again

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

Time is invalidated to pause the views from updating because pause button was hit to pause the audio file.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

  [audioPlayer pause];

 [timer invalidate];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [audioPlayer play];

  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(secondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[viewController release];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(ThirdviewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[secondController release];
}
```

It goes like this for multiple views. As per the application logic user can hit pause on any view to pause the audio file and timer invalidate statement will also pause views from updating. When user will hit pause again to resume audio file it should start updating views from that point onwards. So problem i m having is how to restart the timer again so that it keep on updating views onwards no matter at which view user pauses.

Anyideas how i can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The timers are not supposed to be reused, simply create another one.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)countDown{
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0){
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [self secondViewController];
    }
}
```

Launch your timer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And relaunch your timer:

```
counter = 23;
[self.timer fire];
```

you should adjust this answer for your purposes, because as you can see, the timer is scheduled only for launching `-(void)secondViewController` method

Comment: in each view timer is not constant it varies

Comment: @user1120133 so add the method I've posted above in each view and your problem is solved.